# Do NPCs Throw Parties in The Sims 3?

Tags: the-sims-3

In The Sims 3, you can throw parties and invite people over the phone.  Do you ever get invitations from other Sims?  Or is the player the only one who can throw parties?

Comment: I think it comes with late night, I don't have it so I'm not sure but I was invited to a feast party on the sims 3 seasons by one of my co-workers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get invited to parties, however, I believe that that feature was added in the Late Night expansion.

Comment: Meaning it's not available in the base game?

Comment: @Maxpm I'm going on memory here, but I do not recall being invitied to parties prior to installing Late Night

Comment: I think that the Late Night allows you to because celebrities invite you over, not ordinary people.

Answer (score 2):

NPCs making parties was implemented with the Late Night AddOn. When you are friendly to people they'll invite you to their parties.

You can crash thoose parties too if you're not invited but come anyway

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: When having installed Late Night, they do.